# Failed to load the SafeControl assembly paths for web.config

Tags: error, log

SharePoint 2010 SP2 on a Windows 2008 R2 OS.

The following error has started appearing for our web apps:

> Failed to load the SafeControl assembly paths for web.config.

Comment: Have you looked at the web.config in the 14 hive to see if the assemblies are referenced? Might want to start there.

Comment: could you please share more details about the error, about which assembly it is throwing the error? Check the Web.config of the web apps as well